# How to convert this octave code to python and what is this operator in octave '* and what is it's python equivalent

Tags: python, numpy, octave

what is this operator in octave '* and what is it's python equivalent

What is the python equivalent of the following octave code?

```
a = [2;3]
b = [1;4]
a'*b
```

in short I want to know what is the python equivalent of ( '* ), what is it called and what does it do. How can I implement the same in python. Do I need new libraries. Can someone please convert this part into python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an Octave expert here, but that looks like two operators, `'` and `*`.

Comment: When I type a'*b into Octave (after defining a and b as you did) I get an error. Can you tell me what result you're getting?

Comment: I suggest reading [Octave's operator documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html), which would tell you that `'` is the complex conjugate transpose, and * is matrix multiplication. Both of which are part of plenty of Python packages, including numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> a = [2;3]
a =
   2
   3
>> b = [1;4]
b =
   1
   4
>> a'*b
ans =  14
```

The most literal translation using `numpy` is:

```
In [19]: a = np.array([2,3])[:,None]
In [20]: a
Out[20]: 
array([[2],
       [3]])
In [21]: b = np.array([1,4])[:,None]
In [22]: b
Out[22]: 
array([[1],
       [4]])
In [23]: np.dot(a.T,b)
Out[23]: array([[14]])
```

A shorter expression:

```
In [24]: np.dot([2,3], [1,4])
Out[24]: 14
In [25]: 2*1 + 3*4
Out[25]: 14
```

MATLAB/Octave `'` is the transpose (sometimes also written as `.'`, conjugate transpose). `*` is matrix multiplication, the `np.dot`.  `np.matrix` also uses `*` as matrix multiplication.

---

As pointed out in a comment, I got that backwards.  `.'` is the plain transpose.

Perhaps more important is the fact that MATLAB/Octave matrices are always at least 2d, to tranpose always makes a difference.  `numpy` arrays may be 1d, in which case `np.transpose` does nothing. So in my literal translation I added a trailing dimension to ensure that `a` and `b` are (2,1) in shape.

`numpy` has a `np.matrix` subclass, that was supposed to be more friendly to wayward MATLAB users.  However it was written years ago when MATLAB only had 2d matrices.  So `np.matrix` is always 2d, never more.

`np.matrix(a).conjugate()` is the conjugate transpose, and has a short name `np.matrix(a).H`.  (`.T` is the non-conjugate transpose`.)

```
n [76]: aI = a+0*1j
In [77]: aI
Out[77]: 
array([[ 2.+0.j],
       [ 3.+0.j]])
In [79]: aI.conjugate()
Out[79]: 
array([[ 2.-0.j],
       [ 3.-0.j]])
In [80]: np.matrix(aI)
Out[80]: 
matrix([[ 2.+0.j],
        [ 3.+0.j]])
In [81]: np.matrix(aI).H
Out[81]: matrix([[ 2.-0.j,  3.-0.j]])
```

Comment: OK, got it backwards.  It's been years since I worked with MATLAB, and just keep Octave on hand for this sort of question.  Since I didn't usually work with complex numbers I ignored the difference.